# Azure search: Only the whitespace should be a word delimiter

Tags: c#, azure, search, .net-core

```
QueryType = Simple,
SearchMode = All
Field = "foo!bar"this§is$one%test&for(tokens)in?azure#search"
```

Almost every special character, for example `!"§$%&=?#` seems to be a word delimiter, because a search for "foo" or "bar" or "this" or "is", ... is a match!

We have a apllication with technical fields where special characters are used very often.

Therefore we need a solution where the whitespace is the ONLY word delimitting character!

The usage of the filtering functionality is not a solution for us, because we want to find words in a text like "This is a normal text"!

Is there a solution in azure search or is azure search not the right tool for our requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an analyzer. Within the analyzer, you can define the tokenizer to only use whitespace as delimiters. See the analyzer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search) for implementation details

Comment: I'm now using a CustomAnalyzer with a PatternTokenizer with Pattern "[\\s]". It works fine!